# How do i create a calculated measure that will filter data by days overdue

Tags: mdx

I have a field in my fact table called days overdue.  I would like to create a set that will do the following:  If the days due is between 0 - 29, then 0 - 29 days overdue, if between 30 and 59 days old, then '30 - 59 days overdue.  How would i create this?

Comment: I am using BIDS 2008.  I am new to this and needing all the help i can get.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We need to know what kind of array you're using, or linked list, or my favorite for these things, a vector, etc.

If you were using a vector, you would create your own class to be used as a datatype with things like:

```
Class MyData
{
    String name;
    int daysPastDue; // how you want to factor this is up to you, 
                       // i suggest looking into Java.util.date or Java.util.calendar 
    public MyData
    {
         name = "";
         daysPastDue = 0;
    }
}

Class DoWork
{

public void myWork() // excuse the indent, forgot to put in the class name
{
    vector <MyData> input;
    MyData 0To29 [] = new MyData[input.size()];
    MyData 33To59 [] = new MyData[input.size()];
    MyData item = new MyData();
    int 0To29count = 0;
    int 30To59count = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++)
    {
        item = input.elementAt(i)
        if (item.daysPastDue <= 29)
        {
            0To29[0To29Count] = input;
            0To29Count ++;
        }
        elseif (item.daysPastDue >= 30 && item.daysPastDue <= 59)
        {
            30To59[30To59Count] = input;
            30To59Count ++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

then you have your 2 arrays and can output them as you wish.  however i would recommend starting at daysPastDue = 100000 and decrement it and check the number through the vector until you have all the items in the vector listed.  That way they're all in order from the most past due, to the least and you get the output of exactly how long they've been past due.